Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) Django and Angular
I am gettig error CSRF cookie not set
here is my angular coponent.ts file
sendMessage(nick:string) {

const formData = new FormData();

this.nickname = nick;

formData.append('nickname',this.nickname);

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'X-CSRFToken':this.getCookies('csrftoken')
});

this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/send/', formData, {headers:headers,
      withCredentials:true
}).subscribe(
  (response:any) => {
    if(response.success){
      this.messageStatus = 'Message sent succesfully';
    }
    else {
      this.messageStatus = 'Failed to send message';
    }
  },
  error => {
    this.messageStatus = 'Failed to message'
      console.log('erorr is ',error)
      console.log(this.getCookies('csrftoken'))
      console.log(headers)
    }
  )
}

method getCookies in component.ts
private getCookies(name:string):any{
  const cookieValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + 
        '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return cookieValue ? cookieValue.pop() : '';
}

Here is views.py django
def send_message_to_telegram(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        telegram_nickname = request.POST.get('nickname')
        
        # Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual Telegram bot token
        bot_token = 'My _ token'
        bot_chat_id = '789829434'  # Replace with your bot's chat ID
        
        message = f"Hello, @{telegram_nickname}! This is a message from our bot."
        
        # Sending message via Telegram Bot API
        url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage"
        payload = {
            'chat_id': bot_chat_id,
            'text': message
        }
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
        
        if response.ok:
            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'message': 'Message sent successfully'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Failed to send message'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'message': 'Method not allowed'}, status=405)

here is my settings.py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "http://locallhost:4200",
    "127.0.0.1"
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "accept",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:4200',  
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True 

Isn't my backend get cookie? I am trying to create csrftoken in angular then let the bot send me message from telegram.
Please help me to solve this problem.
